# Deep link QR code opening Safari instead of App in iOS 14

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios14, ios-universal-links

I have implemented deep link / universal links in my app, When i scan QR code in iOS 13 it will opens app and navigating to respected page, but in iOS 14 when i scan QR code it opening in safari, please help me to fix the issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Suggest using one of your two Technical Support requests and get “code level” support on how to fix this. Then update this post to tell the world what Apple suggests doing to fix it.

Comment: Your app might be affected by several changes to Universal Links introduced with iOS 14, e.g. CDN between your app and your web site. See [WWDC 2020: What's new in Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10098/) (CDN starts a14:40). Also test whether your universal links work from a web page.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Also curious if you resolved this as I have the same problem.